# Groovy SQL Multiple ResultSets

Tags: sql, groovy, resultset

I am calling a stored procedure from my Groovy code. The stored proc looks like this

`SELECT * FROM blahblahblah`

`SELECT * FROM suchAndsuch`

So basically, two `SELECT` statements and therefore two `ResultSets`.

```
sql.eachRow("dbo.testing 'param1'"){ rs ->
    println rs
}
```

This works fine for a single ResultSet. How can I get the second one (or an arbitrary number of ResultSets for that matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need [**`callWithAllRows()`**](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/sql/Sql.html#callWithAllRows(groovy.lang.GString,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) or its variant.

The return type of this method is `List<List<GroovyRowResult>>`.

> Use this when calling a stored procedure that utilizes both output
>   parameters and returns multiple ResultSets.

Comment: Is this available in Groovy 1.8, or is this a newer feature? I'm having some trouble getting this to run, based on what I read in that link.

Comment: Or I guess How would I find out what versions its in would be a better question.

Comment: You can [browse gapi/javadoc for each version of Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/). Looks like this was [introduced in Groovy 2.3.1](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.1/html/gapi/groovy/sql/Sql.html)

Comment: Ah okay. Unfortunately my company is behind the times, so I don't have access to the latest version. So while it looks like I'll have to write something for myself, this seems to be the *right* way of doing it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I was able to provide you with a reason for upgrade to put forward in front of the company. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This question is kind of old, but I will answer since I came across the same requirement recently and it maybe useful for future reference for me and others.

I'm working on a Spring application with SphinxSearch. When you run a query in sphinx, you get results, you need to run a second query to get the metadata for number of records etc...

```
// the query
String query = """
    SELECT * FROM INDEX_NAME WHERE MATCH('SEARCHTERM')  
    LIMIT 0,25 OPTION MAX_MATCHES=25;
    SHOW META LIKE 'total_found';
"""

// create an instance of our groovy sql (sphinx doesn't use a username or password, jdbc url is all we need)
// connection can be created from java, don't have to use groovy for it
Sql sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:9306/?characterEncoding=utf8&maxAllowedPacket=512000&allowMultiQueries=true','sphinx','sphinx123','com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')

// create a prepared statement so we can execute multiple resultsets
PreparedStatement ps = sql.getConnection().prepareStatement(query)

// execute the prepared statement
ps.execute()

// get the first result set and pass to GroovyResultSetExtension
GroovyResultSetExtension rs1 = new GroovyResultSetExtension(ps.getResultSet())
rs1.eachRow {
    println it
}

// call getMoreResults on the prepared statement to activate the 2nd set of results
ps.getMoreResults()

// get the second result set and pass to GroovyResultSetExtension
GroovyResultSetExtension rs2 = new GroovyResultSetExtension(ps.getResultSet())
rs2.eachRow {
    println it
}
```

Just some test code, this needs some improving on. You can loop the result sets and do whatever processing...

Comments should be self-explanatory, hope it helps others in the future!